# Custom Alert Dialog looking weird on Android 4.x

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-4.4-kitkat

I want to customize the alert dialog in my Android app, so I started by changing the alertDialogTheme attribute of my app's theme as follows:

**res/values/themes.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert"/>
</resources>
```

Just by doing that, I didn't expected the dialog to look differently from the standard, because the new theme AlertDialogTheme is exactly the same as its parent. It worked properly on Android Lollipop, but in Android Kitkat a white rectangle appears behind the dialog. Here's how it looked like:

[image]

Am I doing anything wrong? Maybe using the wrong parent?

Thanks!

Comment: Just set the background as transparent.

Comment: @zgc7009 Yes, it works on Kitkat, but then the whole dialog gets transparent on Lollipop. I could make two XML files, one for each API, but if there's another way, I'd just like to keep it simple.

Comment: Why don't you use the AppCompat library along with `AlertDialogCompat`?

Comment: @joaquin Never heard of it. You mean this? https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/blob/master/term/src/main/java/jackpal/androidterm/compat/AlertDialogCompat.java

Comment: No! Not at all! I mean official [Android Support Libraries](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html)

Comment: @joaquin Of course! I was already using the AppCompat library. But I was importing android.app.AlertDialog instead of android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog. Now it works beautifully. Thank you!

Comment: Nice. Should I write that as an answer in order to mark this question solved?

Comment: @joaquin Of course, please!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This happens because you´re using `AlertDialog` instead of the relatively new `AlertDialogCompat`. This one brings the same Material Design style dialogs across all platforms and is highly encouraged its use.

To use it, you must be sure that in your Gradle file you have the following line inside your dependencies:
`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1`
(This one is the latest version. Make sure you have all your packages updated by looking into the SDK Manager).

Then in the Activity where you want to show it you must import `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` and use the AlertDialog.Builder exactly as you were using it before.

Comment: I consider this question as answered, although further problems have shown up. Using the support class for AlertDialog, customization gets limited because the color attributes like topDark are no longer taking effect, either placed inside alertDialogTheme or alertDialogStyle. Also, the same solution cannot be applied to DatePickerDialog and TimePickerDialog, as long as these classes don't have their support version so far.

Comment: For those cases you should continue using the defaults Date and Time Pickers included in each API, or use some [unofficial backward port of them](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker).

Comment: The unofficial port may work, I never tried them. But the default ones will have the same problem.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to achieve the same for DateTimePIcker dialog in KitKat?

Comment: @Califf look for some TimePicker Dialog backport on GitHub.

Comment: when i import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog instead of import android.app.AlertDialog; the background disappear but now the title appearing below the blue border instead of above

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by using below code:

```
 <style name="CustomAppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: That's what zgc7009 suggested in the first comment. It works, if I define two XML styles, one for each API. If not, the dialogs will look weird on Android Lollipop. I think joaquin's solution is pretty much simpler, though.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you using AndroidX you'll want to use the following import:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `appcompat` dependency to your build script:

   `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`
2. Replace all usages of `android.app.AlertDialog` with `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`.